# How to fill the "missing time pattern" and "fill them" with particular value efficiently with python?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I'd like to "extend" my row from:

```
+-------------+---------+-------+-------+
| Week Number | Weekday | Time  | Speed |
+-------------+---------+-------+-------+
|           1 | Monday  | 09.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Monday  | 12.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Monday  | 14.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Monday  | 15.00 |     1 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 08.00 |     4 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 10.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 11.00 |     3 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 13.00 |     2 |
+-------------+---------+-------+-------+
```

into the following pattern for each day: 
08.00, 09.00, 10.00, 11.00, 12.00, 13.00, 14.00, 15.00

```
+-------------+---------+-------+-------+
| Week Number | Weekday | Time  | Speed |
+-------------+---------+-------+-------+
|           1 | Monday  | 08.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Monday  | 09.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Monday  | 10.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Monday  | 11.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Monday  | 12.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Monday  | 13.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Monday  | 14.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Monday  | 15.00 |     1 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 08.00 |     4 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 09.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 10.00 |     2 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 11.00 |     3 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 12.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 13.00 |     3 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 14.00 |     0 |
|           1 | Tuesday | 15.00 |     0 |
+-------------+---------+-------+-------+
```

and fill the "missing" with 0.
How can I suppose to do?

I'm using python 3.6 with pandas library.

Comment: what is the dtype for the `time` column?

Comment: timedelta64[ns]. have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Week Number': 1, 'Weekday': ['Monday'] * 4 + ['Tuesday'] * 4, 'Time':['09.00', '12.00', '14.00', '15.00'] * 2,
                  'Speed': [2, 4] * 4})
```

Assuming `times`, `days` and `week_nums` are all values over which to extend the DataFrame

```py
times = ['08.00', '09.00', '10.00', '11.00', '12.00', '13.00', '14.00', '15.00']
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday']
week_nums = [1]
```

Create DataFrame of all possible combinations with `Speed = 0`

```py
from itertools import product
df_combinations = pd.DataFrame(list(product(, days, times, [0])), columns=['Week Number', 'Weekday', 'Time', 'Speed'])
```

Concate both dataframes (the `df_combinations` has to be the 2nd for the duplicate removal!)

```py
df_new = pd.concat([df, df_combinations], ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

Create binary mask of duplicates, remove them and sort the dataframe

```py
df_new = df_new[~df_new.duplicated(subset=['Week Number', 'Weekday', 'Time'], keep='first')]
df_new.sort_values(['Week Number', 'Weekday', 'Time'])
```